# How do I save the state of a datepicker

Tags: android

I'm new to Android dev and re-writing the notepad training app for my own purposes.  Whilst saving the state, I need to do the below, but for a date

```
private EditText mDescriptionText;
private CheckBox mCompleteBoolean;
private DatePicker mDueDate;
```

.

```
String body = mDescriptionText.getText().toString();
Boolean complete = mCompleteBoolean.isChecked();
Date duedate = mDueDate.???; /* << How should this end << */
```

Answer (score 1):

Its either you get it separately and take the day, month, year, etc. or put all the data in a **date** to form a date instance.

**sample:**

```
 int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
 int month = datePicker.getMonth() + 1;
 int year = datePicker.getYear();
```